# Console UI function structure

Tags: java, oop

I am creating an employee management system as a project for my CV and I am relatively new to structuring code in different classes and files in java projects and I was just wondering if someone just answer a couple of questions :).

So just as an overview of the project: I am using Java as the code and then SQL for a database using JDBC as the driver. It will have 2 parts, an HR part and a Non HR part. These will both be separate classes, will have their own functions and both be an extension from a parent 'Employee' class. Some of the basic functionality of these will be:

**HR**

- Search for employees
- Add/Remove employees
- Accept/Decline holiday requests
- Give pay rise
- Promote Employee
- Accept/Decline overtime hours

**Non HR**

- Change name
- Change gender
- Change address
- Change bank details
- Request/withdraw holidays
- Request a meeting

I want to be able to create a UI for the user to be able to interact with the system through the console, the way I was going to do this is have different functions for each state that the program is in. So if it's in the initial state you will enter an ID and if you are in HR it will run the function which shows you the options you can do for HR, then if you are not HR it will run the function which shows you the options you can do for normal employees. This will basically be a load of nested function calls inside the initial 'Start' function. Example of the 'start' function:

```
while (run) {
    if (input == 1) {            // HR ID
        HRScreen();                  // Navigate to the HR screen
    } else if (input == 2) {     // If not HR ID
        nonHRScreen();               // Navigate to the non-hr screen
    } else {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

My question is, where would I place these UI functions? The UI functions are not relevant to either the HR class, or the non-HR class. Would they go into the parent Employee class or should I just put them in their own class? Or is there a better place to put them?

Cheers for the help in advance guys :)

Comment: In Java I first design my objects. Then the database. Only then the user interface.

Comment: What file would the functions go in though? Would they go in one of the ones mentioned above or should I have a separate file

Comment: UI functions should go into UI objects. UI objects depend on business objects, not the other way around. In your case you may have classes such as `CliInterface` and `HrScreen`. Depending on your needs you may also be interested in the [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (to replace bloated `if/else if` statements) and in the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) (for an explicit management of the program's state). Finally, [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask design questions.